# chart.js how to make x-axis labels position top

Tags: javascript, chart.js, x-axis

I'm new to chart.js, and I have a question about making x-axis labels position to the top.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfAQQ.png) is the result that I expected: x-axis labels are on the top.

And this is my attempt:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('weather_chart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'rainfall probability',
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'temperature',
            data: [50, 50, 50, 50],
            borderColor: '#EB6E4B',
            backgroundColor: '#EB6E4B',
        }],
        labels: ['now', '9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm'],
    },
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
  <canvas id="weather_chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

If it is possible, would you take your time to write the answer?

Thanks in advance, and if my question is insufficient, I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Comment: Can you show us any attempts you've made? Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh, I missed it. I truly apologize. I edited it and would this makes work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure all scale related things like position in this namepsaces: `options.scales[scaleId]`. For more config options of the scales you can read the documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('weather_chart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'rainfall probability',
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      label: 'temperature',
      data: [50, 50, 50, 50],
      borderColor: '#EB6E4B',
      backgroundColor: '#EB6E4B',
    }],
    labels: ['now', '9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm'],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        position: 'top'
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
  <canvas id="weather_chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

inside options > scales > xAxes the xAxes is an array, so we can define multiple axis and there configuration like this:

```
options:{
    scales: {
        xAxes: [
            {
                position: 'top',
                ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 80
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Checkout the example here
https://codepen.io/ganeshbkdm/pen/oNeaOwm

Comment: Does not work, he is using V3 and not V2