# How to show labels above X axis in a line chart in chartjs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I Want to achieve something like this [image] in chartjs line chart where i can show labels on top of X axis ,Right now my chart looks like this.
[image]

I could not find it in the chartjs documentation.Pulgins i believe they also don't solve this specific problem

Here is my project you can check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chart.js how to make x-axis labels position top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969098/chart-js-how-to-make-x-axis-labels-position-top)